# Relations between matrix norm and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, determinant, normed-spaces

I was wondering whether there is a way to obtain the determinant of a matrix out of its norm (when the matrix is regular otherwise it is not true). If $A$ is a square matrix of dimension $n\geq 1$, and $\det A\neq 0$, do we have something like?

$$|Ax|_2 \leq \|A\|_{\text{op}} |x|_2 \leq C_n |\det A| \ |x|_2 \leq \cdots$$
or similar? Or maybe a similar estimate for different norms for $A$ and $x$ if needed since many matrix norms are related to eigen- or singular values which are related to the determinant.

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Consider the matrices of the form $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&x\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, with $x\in(0,+\infty)$. All of them have determinant equal to $1$, but their norms are arbitrarily large. Does this answer your question?

Comment: In some sense yes. So the question should be reformulated. For instance. $|Ax|_2\leq \|A\|_{op}|x|_2\leq C_{n,A} |\det A| \ |x|_2$ (i.e. the constant depends on the values of $A$?)

Comment: @Martingalo Sure. Take $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\sqrt{x^2+1}&x\\x&\sqrt{x^2+1}\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Its determinant is $1$, but its norm is arbitrarily large.

Comment: Funily enough if $A$ is invertible and its determinant positive we may find some estimate for its inverse because:
$$\|A^{-1}\| = \frac{1}{\det A} \|Adj(A^\ast)\|$$ but of course the constant is another matrix.

Comment: But anyway there is a bound for the determinant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_inequality
So we have something like $|\det A|\lesssim \|A\|^n$ for a $n\times n$-Matrix.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any way to obtain an upper bound of $\|Ax\|$ using the determinant, because the norm of a matrix can remain unchanged when the determinant approaches zero. E.g. when $x=(1,0,\ldots,0)$ and $A=\operatorname{diag}(1,t,\ldots,t)$, we have $\|Ax\|_2=1$ but $\det A\to0$ as $t\to0$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to prove it, but you might find this exact formula for the norm from Hubbard & Hubbard's Vector Calculus interesting:

> If A is a real 2x2 matrix, then
> $$||A|| = \left(\frac{|A|^2+\sqrt{|A|^4-4(\det A)^2}}{2}\right)^{1/2}$$
> where |A| is the Frobenius norm of $A$.

José Carlos Santos's answer shows that the determinant alone does not carry enough information to determine the norm. For the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ that he considered in his example, we see that as $x \to \infty$, while $\det A \to 1$, the above formula is still able to work because $|A| \to \infty$.

Comment: Could you please give a page reference? I am trying to find it but I can not. Here is the [link](https://notendur.hi.is/mbh6/html/_downloads/Vector%20Calculus%20-%20Hubbard.pdf) I have found.

Comment: Ok, it is exercise 2.8.8.