# Is there any relation between norm and determinant of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was going through an IEEE paper on [Graph Neural Network Model](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1015.7227&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (page 66) and there is one proof where I read

> $\lVert (\partial\Theta/\partial x)(x,w) \rVert \geq (1-\mu)$ thus determinant
>   of $(\partial\Theta/\partial x)(x,w)$ is not null.

Where $\Theta = x -
F_w(x,l)$, $\Theta$ is a vector and $ \mu \in [0,1)$.

Now, I do not understand how they deduce that determinant will be not null on basis of the norm?

Comment: Related, but not duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2357127/relations-between-matrix-norm-and-determinant

Comment: @mvw: Sorry I am new here, can you please tell me how to do that? It should be available because I am also accessing without IEEE membership

Comment: @probably_someone: I have gone through that but I was not able to understand that completely. There they are talking about matrix norm as the upper bound of the determinant. I may be wrong but then doesn't it means that determinant can be zero?

Comment: @mvw: I now put the citeseerx link to the paper. Please check if it is accessible now. You marked correct the correct quotation, the second line was to provide little context so I did not highlight it.

Comment: Aren't they just saying that the matrix is diagonally dominant, hence non-singular ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: But how the jacobian matrix that is given here is diagonally dominant?

Comment: Check the definition of $\Theta$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $(\partial \Theta/\partial x) = I - (\partial F_w/\partial x)$ in the paper. The authors claim that, since (a) $\|(\partial F_w/\partial x)\|\le\mu$ for some $0\le\mu<1$, we have (b) $\|(\partial \Theta/\partial x)\|\ge1-\mu$ and (in turn?) (c) the determinant of $(\partial \Theta/\partial x)$ is nonzero.

It is true that (a) implies (b). However, as you have already noticed, we cannot infer (c) from (b), because we cannot deduce from a matrix's norm that the determinant of that matrix is nonzero.

That said, we can still infer (c) from (a) from the well-known property of [Neumann series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series): since $\|(\partial F_w/\partial x)\|<1$, the Neumann series
$$
I+(\partial F_w/\partial x)+(\partial F_w/\partial x)^2+\cdots\tag{1}
$$
converges and
$$
\bigg(I-(\partial F_w/\partial x)\bigg)\bigg(I+(\partial F_w/\partial x)+(\partial F_w/\partial x)^2+\cdots\bigg)=I,\tag{2}
$$
meaning that $(\partial \Theta/\partial x) = I - (\partial F_w/\partial x)$ is invertible and its determinant is nonzero.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about Neumann series and I was trying to find a relation between (b) and (c), never thought to link directly (a) to (c). It means statement (b) was not needed or it is of no use here?

Comment: @hemantA It isn't needed and it's useless. (b) $\Rightarrow$ (c) was simply a mistaken inference.